# Valheim multiplayer difficulty scaling

Tags: valheim

I am looking for a thorough explanation about Valheim difficulty scaling when playing with multiple people inside a same world. The only information I could find with a quick google was [this wiki](https://valheim.fandom.com/wiki/Level), which states:

> Creature health is further increased by 40% for each nearby player after the first at the moment it spawns.
> Hostile creature damage is further increased by 4% for each nearby player after the first at the moment it spawns.

Are these the only rules on scaling difficulty? Do these rules also effect any boss spawned? And what is the value for "nearby"?

On the second point, could I spawn a boss with a single person and later come back to wreck his poor guy with 10 people?

Comment: I run a dedicated Valheim server -- One thing I do know is monsters do not spawn until they are near a player. I assume that there is one distance calculation for when to spawn (eg. when Player A gets within 50 metres, spawn a greyling) and a second, larger distance for the amount of players (If Player B is within 250 metres, the greyling will have power scaling of 2). But this is an assumption based on the first fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on decompiling the code (version 0.215.2):

- The range used to count players for scaling is 100 (on the horizontal axes only). For comparison, the default build range of a crafting station is 10.
- The maximum number of players that will be counted is 5. Adding more than 5 players will not cause any further scaling.
- Damage dealt to players by non-player characters is increased by **4%** per player beyond the first. The number of players is counted when each attack lands.
- Damage dealt to enemies by anything is reduced non-linearly based on the nearby player count. The formula is `damage / 1 + (playerNum - 1) * 0.3`, which works out to **76%** for 2 players, **62.5%** for 3, **52.6%** for 4, and **45.5%** for 5. The number of players is counted when each attack lands.
- There does not appear to be any scaling of character health values *per se*.
- The only other mechanic that appears to scale on player count is the cap on the number of enemies spawned by an ability (such as, I imagine, Bonemass's blob-spawning ability).

So it appears that you **cannot** abuse the scaling logic by spawning bosses with fewer nearby players and then adding more players later.